Placing objects pstricks in a standalone document
I have a lot of difficulty placing objects with pstricks (I use the package pst-labo in particular).
If I want to place a simple beaker (without having lots of white space around it), I struggle to set the coordinates and I can't manage to do it.
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-labo}


\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(0.25,0)(0.35,1.3)
    \psset{unit=0.5cm}
    \pstTubeEssais[glassType=becher]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}




Provide a desired output or what you do not like so that it is easier to help you!

@azetina I just added the 2 images: the current one and the expected one

It seems that pst-labo dimensions are hard coded. See for example the beginning of this definition used by \pstTubeEssais:
\def\pst@TubeEssais@i{{%
  \addbefore@par{dimen=middle}
  \begin@SpecialObj
  \ifPst@TubeEssais@tubeCoude\pspicture(-1,0)(6,4)\else
    \ifnum\psk@TubeEssais@tubePenche=0 \pspicture(-1.5,0)(1.5,4)\else
      \ifnum\psk@TubeEssais@tubePenche>0 \pspicture(-3,0)(1,4)\else
        \ifnum\psk@TubeEssais@tubePenche<0 \pspicture(-1,0)(3,4)\else
          \pspicture(-2,0)(2,4)%
  \fi\fi\fi\fi

For a becher or a tube the picture geometry is (-1.5,0)(1.5,4).
You can set manually the picture size with \begin{pspicture}(<width>,<height>) and position the \pstTubeEssais with \rput[B](<X>,<Y>) (with the [B] option, (<X>,<Y>) is the position of the center of the subfigure baseline).
Example:
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-labo}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(3,4)
  \rput[B](1.5,0.1){\pstTubeEssais[glassType=becher]}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}


With \psset{unit=0.5cm} and a smaller height to remove the extra white space:
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-labo}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(1.5cm,1.5cm)
  \psset{unit=0.5cm}
  \rput[B](0.75cm,0.1){\pstTubeEssais[glassType=becher]}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-labo}
\begin{document}
\psframebox{\pstTubeEssais[unit=0.5cm,glassType=becher]}
 
\rput*[lb](-3mm,-2cm){\pstTubeEssais[unit=0.5cm,glassType=becher]}   
\end{document}


